# Cannot have names for input and output in keras model.fit

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In short:
Why does this line work -

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=40, verbose=2)
```

And this line doesn't

```
model.fit({"word_input": x_train, "main_output": y_train}, epochs=30, batch_size=40, verbose=2)
```

Further explanation

I am trying to implement LSTM with keras. I have written the following code

```
word_input = Input(shape=(mxlen,), dtype="int32", name="word_input")
x1 = Embedding(len(vocab), 100, input_length=mxlen, weights=[embeddings], trainable=False)(word_input)
x1 = LSTM(100)(x1)

y = Dense(6, activation="softmax", name="main_output")(x1)

model = Model(inputs=[word_input], outputs=[y])
adam = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(optimizer=adam,loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["categorical_accuracy"]) # have to look into it
model.fit({"word_input": x_train, "main_output": y_train}, epochs=30, batch_size=40, verbose=2)
```

I am getting an error in the last line saying "*ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable*". But the exact code works when I change the last line to this

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=40, verbose=2)
```

The reason I want to have names or labels for the input and output in the model.fit is because I want to have mutiple inputs. I got the idea of having labels from the following line of code

```
model.fit(
        {'main_input': X_train, 'pos_input': X_train_pos, 
         'aux_input': X_train_meta, 'dep_input': X_train_dep},
        {'main_output': Y_train}, epochs = num_epochs, batch_size = batch_size,
        validation_data = (
            {'main_input': X_val, 'pos_input': X_val_pos, 
             'aux_input': X_val_meta, 'dep_input' : X_val_dep},
            {'main_output': Y_val}
        ), callbacks=[csv_logger,checkpoint])
```

The entire error screenshot is given below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

It appears that this is an [open-github-issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34114) for tensorflow, currently under development and *named-output* has not yet been implemented using a `dict`.

The [documentation for `Model.fit()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) shows that currently the input, `x` could be a *named-input* by using a `dict`, however, the output, `y` does not accept any `dict` yet.

```py
fit(
    x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None,
    validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None,
    sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None,
    validation_steps=None, validation_freq=1, max_queue_size=10, workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False, **kwargs
)
```

Where,

**INPUT**, `x` = either a numpy array/list-of-arrays or a tensor or a dict or a generator.

> A dict mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors, if the model has named inputs.

**OUTPUT**, `y` = either a numpy array or tensor or not specified when x is a generator.

---

### For Quick Reference

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Comment: @eddard.stark Please consider **`voting up`** as well. Thank you.

Comment: My voting is now blocked. It will open in an hour. I will do it then, I am sorry.